# RichTextBox - counting lines excluding wordwrap

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the below code which searches and replaces text in a richtextbox, but when wordwrap is on, it appears that the linecount is thrown off and it either replaces the wrong line or errors out.

So here's how this is supposed to work (and it does, just not when wordwrap = true).

Let's say I have a richtext box that says "Hello World  blah blah"

**Step 1.** I type "StackOverflow" into textbox1.

**Step 2.** When textbox1.textchanged, I call SandR("Hello world ", textbox1.text.trim, " blah blah"

**Step 3.** The output should be "Hello world StackOverflow blah blah"


Now with the below code, this is working. However, when the text in the richtextbox is long enough to trigger wordwrap, it stops working. For example:

```
Stack Overflow, !

This community restores my faith in humanity. Time and time again, people like  continuously reach out to community questions and help people like me who are struggling to figure out code. It is a learning process for us, and you folks are a great example of what it means to be a good human being.

Thank you all so much for helping users like myself save countless hours of reading material on the internet (that may or may not work due to outdated code, etc) and giving us a chance to learn from someone who is responding to us in real time.

Thanks again !
```

Now if that text had word wrap, and I tried to do SandR("Thanks again ", textbox1.text.trim, " LarsTech!") it would fail.
Are there any amendments to this code that I can make to avoid this issue?

```
Function SandR(ByVal Search As String, ControlText As Object, Replace As String) As String
        Dim text = ""
        Dim startindex = 0
        Dim endindex = 0
        Try
            For i As Integer = 0 To txtRTB.Lines.Length - 1
                text = txtRTB.Lines(i)
                If text.Contains(Search) = True Then
                    startindex = txtRTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
                    endindex = text.Length
                    txtRTB.[Select](startindex, endindex)
                    txtRTB.Text = txtRTB.Text.Replace(txtRTB.SelectedText, Search & ControlText.Text.Trim & Replace)
                End If
            Next
        Catch
            For i As Integer = 0 To txtRTB.Lines.Length - 1
                text = txtRTB.Lines(i)
                If text.Contains(Search) = True Then
                    startindex = txtRTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
                    endindex = text.Length
                    txtRTB.[Select](startindex, endindex)
                    txtRTB.Text = txtRTB.Text.Replace(txtRTB.SelectedText, Search & ControlText.Trim & Replace)
                End If
            Next
        End Try
    End Function
```

For LarsTech:
So this is what it looks like when I use textchanged: https://i.stack.imgur.com/91jL8.jpg
This is what it looks like when I use a button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0QFf.jpg
This is what it looks like when I change the text box and hit the button again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQJwC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I would remove that Try..Catch since any exception that occurs is surely within your control in avoiding it.

It seems unnecessary to go through the Lines collection when you want to replace text, so try iterating through the text *backwards* since replacing text can interfere with the index positions.

```
Dim lastIndex As Integer = txtRTB.Text.Length - 1
While lastIndex > -1
  lastIndex = txtRTB.Text.Substring(0, lastIndex).LastIndexOf(search)
  If lastIndex > -1 Then
    txtRTB.Select(lastIndex, search.Length)
    txtRTB.SelectedText = search & controlText & replace
  End If
End While
```

Also, your function isn't returning anything, so turn that into a Sub routine.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code, it's working with one minor exception: Instead of replacing the text, it seems to be duplicating it. Thanks for the tip about the Sub routine. I'll do a little reading on it!

Comment: @lolikols I was going by what your code was trying to do.  If you are trying to completely replace the search text, then remove the search text from the SelectedText line.

Comment: Hey LarsTech, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I think you've helped me a few times before too :). So the code that I put originally works the way I need it to (just not when word wrap is on): I enter something into a textbox, and when the text is changed it calls SandR("Searching for this text", textbox1.text.trim, "first argument + the textbox.text.trim + this argument"). It finds the entire line that the text is in, and replaces the whole thing. Your code is working great! But it doesn't replace the whole thing. It either duplicates it or when I remove Search, stops working.

Comment: @lolikols Can you give me a small example text?  What's in the TextBox?  What are you searching for?  What's ControlText?  What the Replace text?  That one line of code you should change should look like this, I'm guessing: `txtRTB.SelectedText = controlText & replace`  I used controlText as a string, not an object, in my test.

Comment: @lolikols Instead of "Thanks again !", what should that line end up saying after your function?  Replacing text in a TextChanged event could have weird results.

Comment: It should say "Thanks again StackOverflow Larstech!"

Comment: @lolikols Then put the "search" word back:  `txtRTB.SelectedText = search & controlText & replace`  That worked for me.  If you aren't getting that result, then something else is going on.  If you are doing something in a TextChanged event, I would avoid that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141462/discussion-between-lolikols-and-larstech).

Comment: Updated my post with pictures to show what is happening.